# ¿Cómo modificar el formato de una cadena de fecha?

Tags: r

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo esta fecha:

```
idate <- "27/08/2018"
```

y quiero convertir esta variable idate a `"2018/08/27"`.

Todo parte de que tengo un input de una app en shiny que en una base de datos la fecha esta con el formato `"DD/MM/YYYY"` y en la otra base de datos `"YYYY/MM/DD"` y necesito cambiar de un formato a otro en R.

Answer (score 3):

Se podría hacer con manipulación de strings, pero creo que sería mejor que lo manipules directamente como fecha, usando la clase `Date`.

Una forma es usando la librería `lubridate::`, que tiene unas funciones que facilitan mucho manipular fechas en R.

```
library(lubridate)
idate <- "27/08/2018"
ymd(dmy(idate))
"2018-08-27"
```

`dmy()` transforma el string `idate` en una fecha con ese formato. No hay confusión sobre mes y día.

`ymd()` la pasa al formato que quieres.

Si necesitas que el resultado final sea un string lo haces con `as.character()`.

Con R base y sin necesidad de importar librerías:

```
as.Date(idate, format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Te regresa un objeto de la clase `Date` que también se puede coercionar a `character` si es necesario.

También se podría hacer con manipulación de caracteres.

Usando `tidyverse::`

```
library(tidyverse)
    idate <- c("27/08/2018", "28/08/2018")  # Caso realista: un vector de caracteres.

tibble(fecha_mal = idate) %>% 
      separate(fecha_mal, into = c("dia", "mes", "año")) %>%
      mutate(fecha_bien = paste(año, mes, dia, sep = "/"))
```

Con R base también se puede. La solución que encontré es una abominación, seguro hay una forma más directa de hacerlo:

```
fecha_corregida <- gsub(" ", "/",do.call(paste, as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(idate, "/"))[, c(3,2,1)])))
```

De todos modos funciona.